# Yii2 how to merge two/more rows in one column with GridView

Tags: gridview, yii2, widget

How can I merge two or more rows in one column with GridView in Yii2? The screenshot for 'ETSv2'：

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use kartik gridview for this. http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo

Comment: Hi，Thanks a lot for your quick answers. but I use like this for "Zone", but looks can't work. do you know why? echo GridView::widget([ ...
                'columns' => [
                [
                        'label'=>'Zone',
                        'value' => function($data){
                                return $data->zone;
                        },
                        'group'=>true,
               ]

Comment: which gridview you used.?

Answer (score 1):

In your model:

```
public function getMergedRows()
{
   return $this->name . ' \n ' . $this->eamil;
}
```

in your grid view:

```
[
    'label'=>'Test',
    'attribute'=>'MergedRows',
],
```